# MAMP Pro license record

Tags: license, mamp

I purchased a license for MAMP Pro and copy/pasted the license on the webpage when I ordered it.  But there is no record of the license key on the invoice or on when I login to their support system..  I am retiring this computer and transferring my work to a new computer so I am trying to find my license so I can reinstall MAMP on the new computer.

I've looked through the ~/Library/Application Support folder and /Applications/MAMP Pro/ but I can not find it in a plist file either.  Does anyone know where this is stored or where I can find it?

I've already submitted a support ticket but figured I'd see if someone knows rather than waiting around for them to get back to me.

Comment: I typically resort to my email to find it.

Comment: It wasn't in the invoice.

Comment: If I recall correctly, it typically comes shortly after the invoice. The one I received came from noreply-eng@shareit.com and had "License Key..." in the subject.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The MAMP Pro 1.0/2.0/2.0 upgrade/3.0 serial numbers are stored in the following files:
`"/Library/Application Support/appsolute/MAMP PRO/Registration 1.0"` or
`"/Library/Application Support/appsolute/MAMP PRO/Registration 2.0"` or
`"/Library/Application Support/appsolute/MAMP PRO/Registration upgrade 1.0 to 2.0"` or
`"/Library/Application Support/appsolute/MAMP PRO/Registration 3.0"`

Example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
<key>sn</key>
<string>AABB1122CCDD33AA1</string>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Your serial number is then `string` : AABB-1122-CCDD-33AA1

In MAMP Pro 4 and 5 the serial number is longer and is prefixed with an "MP" (which won't occur in the sn-string).

Files:

`"/Library/Application Support/appsolute/MAMP PRO/Registration 4.0"` or
`"/Library/Application Support/appsolute/MAMP PRO/Registration upgrade 4.x to 5.x"` or
`"/Library/Application Support/appsolute/MAMP PRO/Registration 5.x"`

Example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
<key>sn</key>
<string>11112A2AB333C4444DD55EE66F7F7ABCDEA</string>
</dict>
</plist>
```

The serial number would be: MP-1111-2A2A-B333-C4444-DD55-EE66-F7F7-ABCDE-A

(don't try it – it's probably no valid number because I modified my own serial number massively)

Comment: oh wow, thank you so much... burned my mac and couldn't use their license recovery tool via email since it was some super old email address.. Just saved me a 100$!

Answer (score 1):

- go to https://www.mamp.info/en/forgotSerial.php
- enter your e-mail
- MAMP sent all your earlier purchases that were done with that particular e-mail